# Algorithm for finding conflicting relative order among list elements

Tags: algorithm

I do not know the name of this problem (if I did, I could probably look up a solution).

**Problem**:

Given two lists of integers, `A` and `B`, determine whether there exists an ordering conflict between any two elements `x` and `y`, where both `x` and `y` exist in both `A` and `B`.

For example, consider these two lists:

```
A : 2 3 8 9
B : 3 1 7 2
```

In this case, there exists an ordering conflict `{ 2, 3 }` because those elements appear in the opposite order relative to one another in list `A` as they do in list `B`.

**Trivial cases**

`A` and `B` have no elements in common; no conflicts.

`A` and `B` are the same list; no conflicts.

**Question**

What are some algorithms for solving this problem?

Comment: Can elements be repeated with either list?

Comment: Elements can be repeated, but consider that, when an element that is in both lists is repeated in either list, you definitely have a conflict, unless the repeats immediately follow the first incidence of that element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

edit:

In that case,

1. Create an ordered list of common elements in both lists (ordered by list 2)
2. Using the new list, do the same thing creating an ordered list (ordered by list 1) of common elements.
3. Check if both lists are the same.

To create the ordered list, search for each element in the list you want to set the order with, in the other list.  If it's found, add it to the new list.

This would be O(n*m).

You'd also have to check for duplicates that aren't adjacent which could be done when creating the new lists.

Comment: I changed the problem to clarify that it's whether any two elements are in conflict. You don't get x and y up front.

Comment: Nice! Short, and to the point. I don't think the last part, about checking for duplicates, will be necessary with this approach. That case would be covered by the main algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

Create a hash (or any fast lookup data structure) with keys as values from the first array, and value as the index (position) in the array. Lets call it `S`

```
def Validate(A, B):
    S = CreateLookupTable(A)
    minValueTillNow = -∞
    for i in B:
      if i in S:
         indexInA = lookup(S, i)
         if indexInA < minValueTillNow:
            return false
         minValueTillNow = indexInA

    return true
```

Comment: What is minValueTillNow? It is never written to?

Comment: @ToddFreed Typo. Had swapped the lhs and rhs. Fixed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether this might be optimal, but following is one way to solve:-

1. Create an intersection set of A & B, call it C
2. Elements of C have attributes (indexA, indexB)
3. As we iterate through elements of C, both indexA & indexB should be either decreasing or increasing. If indexA's are increasing and indexB's are decreasing, then we have a conflict relative order.

For example:

```
  A : 2 3 8 9
  B : 3 1 7 2
  C : 2(1,4),3(2,1)
```

As we see, indexA is increasing, whereas indexB is decreasing, so there is a conflict.

Comment: You should probably specify the order of elements in C. For example, you have common-element 2 before common-element 3, and yet both 2 and 3 appear at index 0 in one of the source lists.

Answer (score 0):

You have not provided details but as the question is stated right now it can be done in O(n):

```
int[] A = new[] {2, 8, 9, 10, 3};
int[] B = new[] {2, 1, 7, 3};

int x = 2, y = 3;

int a1 = -1, a2 = -1, b1 = -1, b2 = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < (A.Length > B.Length ? A.Length : B.Length); i++)
{
    if (a1 == -1 && A.Length > i && A[i] == x) a1 = i;
    if (a2 == -1 && A.Length > i && A[i] == y) a2 = i;
    if (b1 == -1 && B.Length > i && B[i] == x) b1 = i;
    if (b2 == -1 && B.Length > i && B[i] == y) b2 = i;

    if (a1 >= 0 && a2 >= 0 && b1 >= 0 && b2 >= 0) 
        break;
}

var result = (a1 < a2) == (b1 < b2) && ((a1 == -1 && b1 == -1) || (a1 != -1 && b1 != -1));
```

You go through arrays only once, until end of arrays or until all variables are assigned. Then it is a simple check if orderings are the same.

Comment: You can't assume the lists have the same length

Comment: I don't think your solution works, because it doesn't even consider all of the elements in either list. But, even if it does work, it only works when the common elements in the two lists are exactly 2, and 3. The solution should find the common elements (if necessary), not start with them hardcoded.

Comment: @ToddFreed,  next time be specific and detailed when asking questions in order to not waste our and your time

Answer (score 0):

1. Get the all of the common element values between the two lists
2. Create 2 lists that contain only common elements ordered by their
   respective source lists (determined by the index of the value in the
   respective source list)
3. reduce those lists only to the unordered elements by removing the ordinator
   List's elements from the list we are testing against (leaving only the "out-of-order" elements from the list we are test against)

The data structures do a lot of the work.  So it's important to understand the capabilities of each of them.  In short, set treats values as-is, while list considers ordering AND value. We could get crazier by using a LinkedHashSet, or do crazy stuff with bitsets and add pretty lambdas, but this is hopefully pretty straight forward.

Example code

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

public class OrderingEnforcer {

    public static List<Integer> getImproperlyOrderedElements(List<Integer> ordinator, List<Integer> toTest) {

        // create a distinct intersection of a and b (order insensitive)
        Set<Integer> intersection = new HashSet<Integer>(ordinator);
        intersection.retainAll(new HashSet<Integer>(toTest));

        // create a sorted list of our intersected set using the
        // indexOf(element)
        // to determine the list ordering
        List<Integer> ordinatorOrderedIntersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(intersection);
        Collections.sort(ordinatorOrderedIntersection, createIndexComparator(ordinator));

        List<Integer> toTestOrderedIntersection = new ArrayList<Integer>(intersection);
        Collections.sort(toTestOrderedIntersection, createIndexComparator(toTest));

        // Now we can create a difference of the two Lists
        toTestOrderedIntersection.removeAll(ordinatorOrderedIntersection);
        return toTestOrderedIntersection;
    }

    private static Comparator<Integer> createIndexComparator(List<Integer> list) {
        return (a, b) -> {
            return Integer.compare(list.indexOf(a), list.indexOf(b));
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: This is definitely similar to the answer I accepted, and maybe @orch drew on your approach. I think his third step is simpler.